# How to translate a placeholder field in react.js

Tags: reactjs

I have done for label ,its workimg fine.I have imported header file as

```
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next'; 

and const { t, ready } = useTranslation(['accountDetails']);
```

How to can I translate this Placeholder:

```
<TextInput mb={'sm'} label={t('first-name')}
 placeholder='First Name'{...form.getInputProps('firstName')} />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use it like in label;

```
<TextInput mb={'sm'} label={t('first-name')}
 placeholder={t('first-name')} {...form.getInputProps('firstName')} />
```

Comment: Thank you so much..Can you tell  me  how to translate dropdown list items ..?{/*City*/}
   <Select
    // readOnly={true}
    // searchabl={true}
    nothingFound='No options'
    mb={'sm'}
    label={t('city')}
    data={cities}
    value={selectedCity}
    onSearchChange={(e) => handleSetCity(e)}
    placeholder={t('pick-one')}
    {...form.getInputProps('city')}
   />